# tail -f but suck in content of the file first (aka `cat -f`)

Tags: tail

I need to display whole file before tracking it for a new changes, not only the last 10 lines (yep, I know it's not *tail* conceptually). In other words, something like `cat -f` would do, if it would ever existed. Tail's man doesn't give me any ideas. The only option I see right now is to somehow combine *cat all but last 10 lines* and *tail -f* output.

Any hints, please?

Comment: `cat $f && tail -n0 -f $f` comes to mind, and checking the man page it looks like `tail -c0 -f $f` might also do what you want (and be better because it does not create a race condition between the two processes where data written could be ignored). I don't have access to a Linux system right now but do either of those do what you want?

Comment: This is useful and I just added such a feature to a programming language: a "tail stream" which can read a file normally from beginnnig to end, and then goes into "tail -f" mode at the end, and can also notice that the file was replaced with a shorter one or truncated, and follow that. You need this to be able to do things like process existing logs (catch up with a backlog) and then begin processing new entries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
tail -f -n+0 /var/log/messages
```

There doesn't seem to be any difference between a `+0` and a `+1`, so this would be equivalent:

```
tail -f -n+1 /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Relevant part of the man page (save people some typing)...

-n, --lines=K output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth